# Excel VBA macro, autofiltered data and hiding columns

Tags: excel, hide, autofilter, vba

I have a problem with excel macro. I am using Excel 2003. I have lots of data in my excel document and i need to make macro so I can see specific data.

All data in this documents is imported from another excel document. I mean it's not value but formula. First row is set for labels of data, like name, surname, number, name of training and so on. Rows below are filled with those data.

What I want to do is: 
1. Filter data by specific column criteria.
2. Use macro which does:
- searching in all columns in range (let's say range G:BV) for value "1"
- when value "1" is found in any cell in the column it stays untouched
- when value "1" isn't found column should be hidden

I was trying hard to find something about my problem, however no success. So far I came up with this code:

```
Sub FindHid()

Dim vFind
Dim rSearch As Range

On Error GoTo 0

vFind = 1

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

For i = 7 To 75

With ActiveSheet.Columns("G:G")
   Set rSearch = .Find(vFind, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False)

   If rSearch Is Nothing Then
      .EntireColumn.Hidden = True

      Else
      .EntireColumn.Hidden = False

   End If
End With
Set rSearch = Nothing
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the best solution to my problem, however it works:

```
Sub FindHid()

Dim vFind
Dim rSearch As Range

'On Error GoTo ErrorHandle
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

vFind = 1

Range("F1").Select

For i = 1 To 68
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

    Set rSearch = Selection.Find(vFind, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
        xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)

        If rSearch Is Nothing Then
            Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True

        Else
            Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

        End If

Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use the `Find` method.
Try with something like:

```
NRows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For R = 2 To NRows
  If Rows(R).Hidden Then
```

Comment: As I mentioned in other anwser, I am uneducated in VBA. So if you give a hint where should i put it? I mean should i replace with ".Find" or?

Answer (score 0):

My code:

```
Sub HideNonOnes()
    Dim rngToSearch As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rngToHide As Range

    Set rngToSearch = Range("G2", Range("G2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))

    For Each rng In rngToSearch.Columns
        If Evaluate("ISNA(MATCH(1," & rng.Address & ",0))") Then
            If rngToHide Is Nothing Then
                Set rngToHide = rng.Range("A1")
            Else
                Set rngToHide = Union(rngToHide, rng.Range("A1"))
            End If
        End If
    Next rng
    If Not rngToHide Is Nothing Then
        rngToHide.Columns.Hidden = True
    End If
End Sub
```

It builds the range `rngToHide` before hiding all these columns in one go.

Comment: This works, but I think the way you're setting `rngToSearch` is a little dangerous. What if column G is empty? You end up with a range of `$G$2:$XFD$1048576`.

Comment: @HeadofCatering Thank you ;) Yes, I wouldn't use that method generally, I just used it to get a range to work with. End() shouldn't generally be used unless we can guarantee there is some data, or check which row/column it returns.

Comment: Hm.. I forgot to mention I am totally uneducated in VBA and all I am trying to do is paste some code and see if it works. Generally I understand it in my own practical way - so probably just don't understand it ;)

And well... this just doesn't work. When I filtered data and used your code, all columns start from G hid. That's not quite what I was after.

I can provide you example of how it looks, however I don't know if I can attach anythin on stackoverflow.